# IBM Worklight - "Client init failed. Connection to the service is not available."

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I've created an Android app in Worklight Developer Edition. 
When I change the `connectOnStartup` property to `true` in the `initOptions.js` file and then install the application on the device, on startup, in LogCat I see:

```
Client init failed. Connection to the service is not available.
```

And in the app there's a dialog with:

```
The application failed connecting to the service.
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your device and host are using the same WiFi network...

To verify your **device** is able to connect to the server, open a mobile browser app (either the stock app or Chrome or otherwise, doesn't matter) and load `http://your-server-address:10080/your-project-name/console`

- If you do not see Worklight Console, then you have a network issue here, likely not using the same network or you are blocking some ports, etc
- If you do see Worklight Console, then we have another problem here...

Comment: When I did it yesterday I was at work and with the WiFi of there. Now that I've tried at home with my personal WiFi, I've done, it works fine. That would possibly be because of permissions or firewall?

Comment: Yes. You need to make sure that 1) your device is connected to the work wifi. 2) to do the tests I've mentioned in my answer. 3) talk with your IT department.

Comment: By the way, i've downloaded the push notifications project from "Woklight getting started" and I've installed it in my device with the proper API key and senderId. It's working fine but I have no idea how to do the test of sending push notifications to the device. I've read about using the the PushBackendEmulator.jar but is there another way of doing it?

Comment: Please don't mix questions; this question is not about how to use the push notifications sample but about why your app does not connect to the Worklight Server. --------- You have two ways to use the Backend **simulation**: 1) use the provided .jar file as explained in the push notifications training module, or 2) invoke the adapter procedure by right-clicking the adapter > invoke procedure > specify username and message.

Comment: @IdanAdar i can see the worklight console,but same error s coming in push notification demo?

Comment: Make sure your application points to the correct worklight server address as well as connected to the same network.

Comment: wat do u mean by that?

Comment: Something in your network is not OK, either in the server or client or network. Check everything.