# IBM Worklight : Android Application - Connection to the service is not available

Tags: android, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

So, I'm developing Android Application using Worklight. I'm also using wamp server and cordova media for the application. When I run the application in the device, I receive the following error in logcat :

```
     06-26 16:56:39.008: E/libEGL(5184): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
     06-26 16:56:52.081: E/NONE(5184): Client init failed. Connection to the service is not available.
```

Based on this post, [IBM Worklight - "Client init failed. Connection to the service is not available."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20860974/ibm-worklight-client-init-failed-connection-to-the-service-is-not-available)
I've tried to open the console from the tablet and it is able to connect. And it is also using the same wifi.

The application can run but some of the feature did not work in the app, and the database is not loaded.
I've added permissions for using cordova media in the manifest and also specified the target Sdk. Does anyone know or have experienced this?

UPDATE :

Here is the full warn log :

```
     06-28 13:15:40.658: W/com.worklight.androidgap.analytics.WLAnalytics(16503): TLF_configurator.enable was called, but the required Tealeaf libraries are not present in the classpath.
     06-28 13:15:43.140: W/PluginManager(16503): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to Utils.writePref blocked the main thread for 33ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
     06-28 13:15:43.170: W/PluginManager(16503): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to Utils.writePref blocked the main thread for 26ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
     06-28 13:15:43.711: W/PluginManager(16503): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to Utils.loadSkin blocked the main thread for 535ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
     06-28 13:15:47.675: W/PluginManager(16503): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to NativeBusyIndicator.show blocked the main thread for 85ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
     06-28 13:15:48.065: W/NONE(16503): Your application is using the WL.OptionsMenu API. Note that, if your application targets Android 3.0 (API level 11) or higher, WL.OptionsMenu might have no effect, depending on the device.
     06-28 13:15:48.215: W/PluginManager(16503): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to Utils.writePref blocked the main thread for 32ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
     06-28 13:15:48.876: W/PluginManager(16503): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to Utils.writePref blocked the main thread for 57ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
     06-28 13:15:49.096: W/PluginManager(16503): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to NetworkDetector.log blocked the main thread for 21ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
     06-28 13:15:49.376: W/PluginManager(16503): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to Media.startPlayingAudio blocked the main thread for 60ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
```

Comment: set <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ...> in AndroidMainfest.xml

Comment: @AmitPrajapati The first error logs is solved by adding that, Thanks. But the second error still exist though.

Comment: i think your not waiting for device ready and one more i hope you have set * on access origin in res->confix.xml

Comment: @AmitPrajapati I've set both of those and still receive the same error.

Comment: Please follow this it may hep you becz i do't know worklite i know only phonegap http://wpcertification.blogspot.in/2012/03/connecting-to-database-from-worklight.html

Comment: @Anita, the error is not enough; if you create a blank new app in Worklight that all it does is connectOnStartup:true in initOption.js, do you manage to connect to the Worklight Server? What do you see in logcat with this new app?

Comment: @IdanAdar yes, I can connect to the Worklight server. And it's also working on the device. Any idea?

Comment: If in a new app you are able to connect to the server, but in your other app you cannot, then you have a problem in your app and the current question does not help in determining the issue. Provide more information on what you are implementing and how you are implementing it as well better describe the error. Please edit the question with this information - not in comments.

Comment: @IdanAdar Hey Idan, the second error was my mistake for forgetting to add the mysql connector. But still in the android device, the application is not working properly. I've updated the warning log in the question.

Comment: You are still not explaining what it is that you are doing in your app so I can't help until you do that. If you want, add a demo Worklight project showing you problem so it could be debugged.

Comment: @Idan so it's basically a game where I'm using cordova media and camera plugin. There's also database (wamp). And I'm using HTC Flyer for the testing with Android API 13.

Comment: There is still not enough information. Explain exactly what is *not working*.

Comment: @IdanAdar here is the link of the demo https://www.dropbox.com/s/87bontxzvuzulit/KokoATZDemo.zip Thankyou so much Idan for your help

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the app in Nexus 5 running Android 4.4 and client init was success in my case. There were all sort of errors, but not the one you mention.

I suggest to try to:

- Delete the app from the device and re-install
- Delete the native folder, re-build and re-install